# Why when I open a big file by editor,cpu usage is high?

Tags: performance, file, file-io, io, cpu

Should it be disk IO not CPU?
editor read file from disk to memory,is the process of editor to handle file complex?

Comment: what editor? you may need to look into how your editor works

Comment: sublime,maybe when it load a big file,the ui has a progress bar to show the loading percentage,so the cpu is high.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a text editor that parses the contents of that file.  If you only load the file to RAM the DMA will do the loading and will not use the CPU for that. but in your case the text editor is parsing that file for syntax hilighting and/or building auto-compleate indexes causing high CPU usage.